# Activating virtualenv ENV

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv in my Documents file: `virtualenv django_1`

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\Enviorments>virtualenv django_1 Using base prefix c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32 New python executable in C:\Users\admin\Documents\Enviorments\django_1\Scripts\python.exe

Installing setuptools, pip, wheel, ... done.

How do I activate it?
`source django_1/bin/activate` doesn't work.

I've tried: 
`source C:\Users\admin\Documents\Enviorments\django_1/bin/activate` and every time I get :

> 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+activate

Answer (score 3):

`source` is a Unix command, so won't work on Windows.

Instead run

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\Enviorments\django_1\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)